# Error when using cv.tree

Tags: r, tree

Hi I tried  using the function `cv.tree` from the package `tree`. I have a binary categorical response (called `Label`) and 30 predictors. I fit a tree object using all predictors.

I got the following error message that I don't understand:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
>         cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame

The data is the file 'training' taken from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/higgs-boson/data) site.

This is what I did:

```
x <- read.csv("training.csv")
attach(x)
library(tree)
Tree <- tree(Label~., x, subset=sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2))
CV <- cv.tree(Tree,FUN=prune.misclass)
```

Comment: what programming language ist this? You should add a tag so people interested in this lang. can find your question

Comment: Based on a quick google, it sounds like R

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs once *cv.tree* calls *model.frame*.  The 'call' element of the tree object must contain a reference to a data frame whose name is also not the name of a loaded function.

Thus, not only will subsetting in the call to *tree* generate the error when *cv.tree* later uses the 'call' element of the tree object, using a dataframe with a name like "df" would give an error as well because model.frame will take this to be name of an existing function (i.e. the 'density of F distribution' from the stats package).

Comment: Dude you saved me so much time!! Thank you, I need to stop calling my dataframes 'df'

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the dependent variable list.  The following works, but I think you need to read the problem description more carefully.  First, setup the formula without weight.

```
x <- read.csv("training.csv")
vars<-setdiff(names(x),c("EventId","Label","Weight"))
fmla <- paste("Label", "~", vars[1], "+", 
           paste(vars[-c(1)], collapse=" + "))
```

Here's what you've been running

```
Tree <- tree(fmla, x, subset=sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2))
plot(Tree)
$size
[1] 6 5 4 3 1

$dev
[1] 25859 25859 27510 30075 42725

$k
[1]   -Inf    0.0 1929.0 2791.0 6188.5

$method
[1] "misclass"

attr(,"class")
[1] "prune"         "tree.sequence"
```

You may want to consider package rpart also

```
urows = sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)/2)
x_sub <- x[urows,]
Tree <- tree(fmla, x_sub)
plot(Tree)
CV <- cv.tree(Tree,FUN=prune.misclass)
CV

library(rpart)
tr <- rpart(fmla, data=x_sub, method="class")
printcp(tr)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = fmla, data = x_sub, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] DER_mass_MMC                DER_mass_transverse_met_lep
[3] DER_mass_vis               

Root node error: 42616/125000 = 0.34093

n= 125000 

        CP nsplit rel error  xerror      xstd
1 0.153733      0   1.00000 1.00000 0.0039326
2 0.059274      2   0.69253 0.69479 0.0035273
3 0.020016      3   0.63326 0.63582 0.0034184
4 0.010000      5   0.59323 0.59651 0.0033393
```

If you include weight, then that is the only split.

```
vars<-setdiff(names(x),c("EventId","Label"))
```

Comment: Hmm..the only difference I can see is that I actually use a subset of the data in the tree function. More explicitly I write: Tree <- tree(Y ~., data=X, subset=sample(1:nrow(X), nrow(X)/2))  and then cv <- cv.tree(Tree,FUN=prune.misclass) ..and then I get error message above...

Comment: The subset produces results also, see above.  Using version tree_1.0-35.  Can you need to create a sample data set that is similar to your data set, and add to the original question.

Comment: Yes good idea. I have done that now, but now I just get the problem that I get a single node. I have probably made the columns too similar, which they of course not are in my real data

Comment: Try working with a smaller number of samples, and independent variables.  I would start with X having one column from the real data, and get that to work, then add more columns.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help again. I tried with a sample of 50 and take just one column (from the real data that is), but I got the same error message...

Comment: Try using the command dput on the sample data set in order to share your data so other can repeat the error.  I have not used the command before, so I'm not sure how large the output is.  Also, there may be an option to share a file in edit mode.

Comment: I have now changed the question where the data is attached

Comment: OK, I adjusted the answer for the actual data.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I tried not to subset in the cv.tree function, but create the data subset in advance, and use that as data argument - just as you did above. And it worked. Thanks for everything