# Error trying to do cross validation after a classification tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am trying to run a simple classification tree using the tree package. I have taken the code from a textbook, copied one by one, but it doesn't work, no matter what I do.

```
library(ISLR)
library(tree)
C = Carseats
C$HighSales = ifelse(C$Sales<=8,"No","Yes")
C = C[,-1]

set.seed(2)
train = sample(1:nrow(C), 200)
carseats.test = C[-train,]
high.test = C$HighSales[-train]

tree.carseats = tree(HighSales~., C, subset = train)
tree.predict = predict(tree.carseats, carseats.test, type = "class")
table(tree.predict,high.test)
(93+48)/200

set.seed(3)
cv.cs = cv.tree(tree.carseats, FUN = prune.misclass)

I am getting the following error:

Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

I have looked at the help of the function. It requires a tree object, which is what I put inside.

What can be the problem ? The code is identical to the textbook and to other websites who quote the book.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. One is related to the formula in `tree`:

> formula   - A formula expression. The left-hand-side (response) should be **either a numerical vector when a regression tree will be fitted or a factor, when a classification tree is produced**. The right-hand-side should be a series of numeric or factor variables separated by +; there should be no interaction terms. Both . and - are allowed: regression trees can have offset terms.

So, we should instead have

```
C$HighSales <- factor(ifelse(C$Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes"))
```

Next, there's a problem with how `cv.tree` deals with variables (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26314062/1320535)). Doing something like

```
mydf <- C
tree.carseats <- tree(HighSales ~ ., mydf, subset = train)
```

works. The issue is that there's a function called `C` and `cv.tree` refers exactly to this function rather than your dataset.